# Any built-in Python lib or function for best (most exact) string matching like routing table? If not, is my code most effecient?

Tags: python, routes, string-matching

Code example:

```
# Something
dept_dict = {
    # Generally, employee code starting with '15' means Department A, '16' B, '17' C.
    '15': 'Department A',
    '16': 'Department B',
    '17': 'Department C',

    # Exception: sub dept '15.233' and '17.312' belonged to dept A and C but now B.
    '15.233': 'Department B',
    '17.312': 'Department B',

    # Exception: employees who had transferred to another department.
    '15.233.19305': 'Department C',
    '15.330.19306': 'Department B',
}
# Requirement: use exception (exact matched) item if it exists, otherwise "fall" to general item.


# Is there any built-in function implement the following?
def get_dept(emp_code):
    dept_name = None
    for i in range(len(emp_code), -1, -1):
        dept_name = dept_dict.get(emp_code[0:i])
        if dept_name:
            break
    return dept_name


# Test code:
print(get_dept('15.233.19305'))  # The employee who transferred to Dept C from Dept A
print(get_dept('15.233.19300'))  # The employee who belongs to a sub dept, all employees of which have transferred to Dept B from Dept A
print(get_dept('15.147.13500'))  # The employee who belongs to Dept A just like most of the employees
print(get_dept(''))
```

result:

```
Department C
Department B
Department A
None
```

For function "get_dept", is there any built-in function which have already implemented it? Did I reinvent the wheel?

I've read some posts with tile "most exact matching" on this site, but most of them are about "fuzzy searching", for example matching "department" with ["depatment", "depart"], which is not what I want. When I search "routing table", I got posts like "URL matching", which is not what I want, too.

It seems to be an underlying technology used by "routing table".

If there is no such built-in function, the question would be: is my implementation most efficient? Should I use, for example binary search or something else?

---

(Edited)

Thanks to someone who commented (but somehow deleted it). The comment said that building a Trie might be an option. If the dict is not frequently changed and there are lots of queries, overhead of building a Trie could be ignored.

Comment: you can make use of `re` module

Comment: In your example, department names are separated by `'.'`, that allows for more optimal solutions. Do you need something that generally works and is this just an example? Or are you looking for the optimal solution for this specific problem (with a larger data set conforming to the same rules)?

Comment: @Grismar 1. This is just an example. 2 actuall this question is for technology dicussion. In my real case, the script runs every 2 hourse, queries a dict with less then 30 keys for 2 or 3 times. So solution in the example is OK to me. But we not only writing code for job task but also for improving our selves, right? I just want to know if my code is "ugly" and if there is a better solution. For example someone mentioned "Trie", which is a very good point. Despite I may not use in this script, but next time when I have to deal with heavier query load or larger data set, it might be helpful

Comment: @Grismar In the real world I'm writing CI pipeline code. The only parameter I can get is SW build name, and I have to "guess", for example release name, version name, branch name, ect., based on the SW build name. Depite there is naming convention, there are also lots of exceptions. Asking the team to strictly follow naming convention or asking up-stream to pass additional parameters are out of my control, so I have to adapt to them. My code has resolved my problem, but here I'm asking for more general solution in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

This reduces your worst case from 11 dictionary lookups to 3.  Assuming there are no silver bullets you might consider something along these lines.

Example:

```
def get_dept(emp_code):
    
    emp_sub_codes = emp_code.split(".")

    while emp_sub_codes:
        dept_name = dept_dict.get(".".join(emp_sub_codes))
        if dept_name:
            return dept_name
        emp_sub_codes = emp_sub_codes[:-1]

    return None
```